# INDIRECT cell reference using string with curly brackets "{ }"

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

this code is to get the range of 2 columns (A and D) and it's working fine:

```
={A1:A6,D1:D6}
```

Now in my case, this cell reference is a string, so I want the string to be: **"{A1:A6,D1:D6}"**

so to get the value of that range using string as range, I usually use **indirect()**. The problem is that it does not work with curly brackets. For example, if I use:

```
=indirect("{A1:A6,D1:D6}")
```

it will give me an error. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one way would be doing it like this:

```
={INDIRECT(SPLIT(G8, ",")), INDIRECT(INDEX(SPLIT(G8, ","),,2))}
```

[image: 0]